# How can select samples with apply method without replacing in a loop

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

> I would like to select "dmin" numbers of samples in each group(group by) in a dataframe and add them to another empty dataframe.

If total number of samples which we need is not enough, again select new "dmin" numbers of samples and add to the dataframe. This loop needs to be repeated until total number of samples we need is covered.

I am new in coding and can not understand the problem, but samples are selected just one time in my code and can not be repeated time by time in a group.

Another problem is that in each group of that dataframe, the number of records might go to be less than value of "dmin" in the loop and the code might face this problem "number of samples in the group is less than "dmin".
I was wondering if you could help me. This is part of my code:

```
while V > 0:
    x6 = result_sort[result_sort['K'] > p_ratio].groupby('position').apply(lambda x:x.sample(dmin).reset_index(drop=True))
    A = x6.append(A)
    S = len(A)
    V = V_total - S
```

Comment: Use `replace=True` in `sample`?

Comment: In apply method, there is no replace option.

Comment: please re-read my comment, did i say `replace` in `apply` or `sample`?

Comment: I meant that I do not know if it is possible to use sample method with groupby together . as a result I used apply method.

Comment: `.apply(lambda x:x.sample(dmin, replace=True)...`

Comment: It has also that problem which could not select samples in the loop and just one time samples are selected.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem with adding another condition in while loop.